# Cannot connect to my SQL Server database with NestJS

Tags: sql-server, nestjs

After reading the documentation, I've encountered a problem, I'm getting the error unable to connect to the database. I'm trying to connect to a local SQL Server database, using NestJS. I enabled a user `sa` and set its password. I also enabled TCP/IP connection and confirmed the port from SQL Server. I'm wondering what am I missing or doing wrong?

```
 @Module({
imports: [
ConfigModule.forRoot({
  envFilePath:'.env',
  isGlobal: true
}),
TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
  type: 'mssql',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 1433,
  username: 'root',
  password: 'root',
  database: 'test',
  autoLoadEntities: true,
  synchronize: true,
  
}),
],
controllers: [AppController, EstadoProyController],
providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Answer (score -2):

check this items:
1- sql server running
2- check your port or host

Comment: sql server is running, port is 1433, and what do you mean by check your host ? i tought if its locally host ='localhost' and if its a cloud server it should be 127.0.0.0 just like in the sql server configuration manager properties tcp/ip where is shows the ip address

Comment: we can change sql server port and customize that
and sometimes windows defender or .. prevent to run service on localhost